# Class 'Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_DateRange' not found

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing reporting tools and want to get website stats from google analytics.  Problem is only some of the test scripts from the Analytics examples are working.
This works fine:

```
$accounts = $analytics->management_accountSummaries
  ->listManagementAccountSummaries();
```

This throws an error (see title of post):

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_DateRange();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What branch/commit are you using of the [PHP client libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)? [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) was only released in April. Also how are you including the classes into the namespace? Are you using the v1-branch with the `require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';` syntax or are you using the master branch with the `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` It may just mean you need to update your client library.

Comment: require_once '../../google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

Comment: So it sounds like you are on the v1-master branch then, what version are you on? Analytics Reporting API V4 was only [merged](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/commit/1f6e62d7a99edc0ad9cb33b5fc5e2446b377b9c6) into the v1-master branch 11 days ago. I will put instructions in the answer below.

Comment: I think the client library I installed is v4. I'm having success running core reporting api service account code examples in the v3 php examples.

Comment: V4 is the API version, when did you clone the PHP client library? The error in the title, and the fact that you are able to call the V3 API tells me that the version of the PHP client library you are using is from before the Analytics Reporting API V4 was released (11 days ago for the v1-master branch). In order to use the most recently released APIs you need to update your PHP client library See my instructions below on how to do that.

Comment: One final thing you may need to do is [enable the Analytics Reporting API V4](https://console.developers.google.com//start/api?id=analyticsreporting.googleapis.com&credential=client_key) in the developer console. As this API is completely separate from the V3 API you need to enable it separately.

Comment: (this is what I found)Add credentials to your project

Find out what kind of credentials you need
Calling Analytics Reporting API V4 from a platform without a UI
2 You already have credentials that are suitable for this purpose

Comment: Since you clicked that link if you look at the "enabled API's" you will see that both "Analytics" and "Analytics Reporting" are both enabled.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Both are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated Answer

It appears that there was that there is a missmatch in capitalization. Wherever you have `..._Analyticsreporting...` you should substitue `..._AnalyticsReporting...`.

#### Original Answer

The Analytics Reporting API was merged into the [Google API php client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/commit/1f6e62d7a99edc0ad9cb33b5fc5e2446b377b9c6) on May 9th 2016.

What you will need to do is:

```
cd ../../google-api-php-client
git checkout v1-master
git pull
```

1. Go to the directory where you stored your php client library
2. Checkout the v1-master branch if you have not done so already
3. Do a git pull.

Should **step 2.** fail because you are on a branch that is over a year old then do a `git pull` on the master branch checkout `v1-master` and do a `git pull` again.

You can always look to see if `../../google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/AnalyticsReporting.php` is present too.

Comment: Mikes-MacBook-Air:google-api-php-client mikev$ git checkout v1-master
Already on 'v1-master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/v1-master'.
Mikes-MacBook-Air:google-api-php-client mikev$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
Mikes-MacBook-Air:google-api-php-client mikev$

Comment: It is [capitalization](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/AnalyticsReporting.php#L193): `class Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRangeValues extends Google_Collection` Use an upper case R in AnalyticsReporting.